# Can I remove the SanDisk security file from my trash?

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, delete, trash

Some flash drives have a special file on them that can be used for encryption purposes and is supposed to secure your data. I never use them. So I moved it off the flash drive into my Ubuntu trash, and its stuck there, unable to completely delete.

I am using the latest Ubuntu software, the file is:

```
trash:///SanDiskSecureAccess.2.2
```

When I tried to empty my trash, it would give the weird error "error unable to complete."

Can someone help me clear it out?

Comment: "...unable to completely delete" why? What happens when you try? Any errors? Any problems with the mouse, screen, keyboard, etc?

Comment: If you put something from a removable device into trash, Ubuntu will create a trash folder on that device and move it there. Something like a folder called `.Trash-1000` (you must enable showing hidden files to see it) in the device's root directory. Your trash will then display the combined content of both your local user's trash folder and those of all connected devices, if any.

Comment: ByteCommander it worked! My trash is now empty, thx.  And to answer Mikewhatever when I tried to empty my trash, it would say "error unable to complete"  wierd.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't empty the trash in the usual way then you can often do so by deleting the trash folder. As Byte Commander said, each device on which files are deleted to the trash gets its own trash folder, which is hidden because it starts with `.`:

> If you put something from a removable device into trash, Ubuntu will
>   create a trash folder on that device and move it there. Something like
>   a folder called `.Trash-1000` (you must enable showing hidden files to
>   see it) in the device's root directory. Your trash will then display
>   the combined content of both your local user's trash folder and those
>   of all connected devices, if any.

– [**Byte Commander**](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) [Aug 16 at 21:49](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946909/can-i-remove-the-sandisk-security-file-from-my-trash#comment1505846_946909)

The `.` prefix to hide files is just a convention and there is no technical impediment against you viewing, modifying, or deleting such files. In most graphical file browsers including Nautilus ("Files"), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> views hidden files. You can press it again to re-hide them.

If you prefer to use the terminal, add `-A` to your `ls` commands to show hidden files. You can probably delete the files in a graphical file browser or with the `rm` command. To "hard delete" them in the file browser--rather than sending them (back) to the trash--you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This works in virtually all graphical file browsers (it even  works in Windows).

You should be extra careful when using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>--for example, make sure you don't have anything selected that you don't want to delete--because it's quite often not possible to recover files after you've deleted them, and even when it is possible, it is almost always a hassle and the files may be damaged. You should apply the same care with `rm`.

<sub>(You [indicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946909/can-i-remove-the-sandisk-security-file-from-my-trash#comment1507503_946909) you were able to delete the files based on Byte Commander's explanation, but you did give the specific method you used, so I've included some information about that here for the benefit of others. This answer is mainly to help others who have the same problem you had and find your question by searching.)</sub>